# referencing object inside another object javascript

Tags: javascript, object, reference, pass-by-reference

So I have two different set of objects:

```
var house = {};
house["01"] = {hID: "01", neighbh: "00001", name: "house 1"};
house["02"] = {hID: "02", neighbh: "00001", name: "house 2"};
house["03"] = {hID: "03", neighbh: "00002", name: "house 3"};
house["04"] = {hID: "04", neighbh: "00003", name: "house 4"};

var neighborhood = {};
neighborhood["00001"] = {id: "00001", name: "first neighborhood", houses: {} };
neighborhood["00002"] = {id: "00002", name: "second neighborhood", houses: {} };
neighborhood["00003"] = {id: "00003", name: "third neighborhood", houses: {} };
```

I want to be able to reference the house objects inside houses {} within neighborhood. But filter them to their respective neighborhood. i.e. house["01"] should go in the neighborhood["00001"] (those that have the neighborhood id matching house neighbh). This is so that I can have all the houses in one different object, but still be able to make changes to them through the neighborhood object. Hopefully I have managed to make myself clear.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? In particular, I don't understand this sentence: "But filter them to their respective neighborhood. i.e. house["01"] should go in the neighborhood["00001"] (those that have the neighborhood id matching house neighbh)."

Comment: so as an example, house["01] (has a neibh of 00001) because that id (per say) matches the neighborhood id of neighborhood["00001"] it should be referenced inside that one, does that explain it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are passed and stored by reference.  So, suppose you had a master array of all the houses:

```
var houses = [
    {hID: "01", neighbh: "00001", name: "house 1"},
    {hID: "02", neighbh: "00001", name: "house 2"}
];
```

And, you then had an array of neighborhood objects that each had some identifying information about the neighborhood and then a list of houses that are in that neighborhood:

```
var neighborhoods = [
    {id: "00001", name: "first neighborhood", houses: [houses[0], houses[1]]} 
];
```

In a structure like this, there is only one copy of each house object.  You can modified it via any of the references you have.  So, you can modified it via the master houses array.  Or, you can modified it via the houses array inside the neighborhood.  Each points to the exact same house object.  So, when you modify it in one place, you are modifying the actual house object and everyone who has a reference to that particular house object will see those modifications.

---

So, in the structure you postured (which uses objects as containers instead of the arrays I used to hold multiple items). I think you can fill that out like this and accomplish what you're asking for:

```
var house = {};
house["01"] = {hID: "01", neighbh: "00001", name: "house 1"};
house["02"] = {hID: "02", neighbh: "00001", name: "house 2"};
house["03"] = {hID: "03", neighbh: "00002", name: "house 3"};
house["04"] = {hID: "04", neighbh: "00003", name: "house 4"};

var neighborhood = {};
neighborhood["00001"] = {id: "00001", name: "first neighborhood", houses: [house["01"], house["02"]]};
neighborhood["00002"] = {id: "00002", name: "second neighborhood", houses: [house["03"]] };
neighborhood["00003"] = {id: "00003", name: "third neighborhood", houses: [house["04"]] };
```

FYI, it seems like the list of houses in a neighborhood should be an array, not an object.

Comment: The problem with this is since I will be adding more houses and neighborhoods I need to be able to have this done automatically, not sure if I can have a function that uses for var obj in in order to sort through the houses and then be able to access the correct ones from neighborhoods. Furthermore they will not be in order (hence the use of a map object). I would have to check all the houses and find those that have a matching neighbh with a neighborhood id

Comment: @SantiagoEsquivel - see the latest code I added.  As long as you're double maintaining information by storing information in multiple places (such as a neighborhood id in the house object and a separate list of houses contained within a neighborhood, you will have to maintain that duplicity.  There is no automatic way to solve that.  It's like a database index.  Whenever you add/remove/modify the database, the index has to be updated too.   Creating yourself a set of methods for making modifications will make it easy to centralize the maintenance.

Comment: Ok, I think this will help, I might have been looking for a more complicated approach, but simply pushing the house [id] in the respective neighborhood when there is a post and making sure I create instance of the object in houses I should be fine. Thanks.